# Scope function not working with JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm developing an app with AngularJS. I have this function declared in the controller:

```
$scope.showModal = function(modalId){
    alert(modalId);
    $(modalId).openModal();
};
```

Then I have a hyperlink which calls this function:

```
<a ng-click="showModal('#modal{{jsonObject._id}}');" >link</a>
```

The JSON Object ID is "1". In the navigator, I can see that the HTML code of the link is this:

```
<a ng-click="showModal('#modal1');" >link</a>
```

But when I click the link, the alert shows this:

```
#modal{{jsonObject._id}}
```

Instead of "#modal1".

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is jsonObject in your scope ?

Comment: Mixing angular and jquery that much is bad practice. You might be interested in [angular-ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which offers angular-integrated modals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `ng-click` you are in the angular context, so you have not to use `{{}}`.

```
<a ng-click="showModal('#modal'+jsonObject._id);" >link</a>
```